# Access Custom Owner Fields in VisualForce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, sobject

I have a VisualForce email template that retrieves merge data from a custom object (`Enquiry__c`).

The owner is an individual `User`.  I want to access the value of a custom field on the `User` object.

I'm able to access some standard fields (E.g., Email) of the owner by way of `{!relatedTo.owner.Email}`, but I'd like to access the values of custom fields.

Suppose I have a custom field called `Acuity_Calendar_ID__c` on the `User` object.

I try `{!relatedTo.owner.Acuity_Calendar_ID__c}`, but it doesn't work.  I get the following Error:

```
Error: Invalid field Acuity_Calendar_ID__c for SObject Name
```

Apparently, `relatedTo.owner` is a `Name` object.  I guess [these are the only fields I have access to](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_name.htm)?

I'm not the original author of the email template, nor am I a Salesforce developer.  I'm just trying to add a sentence to an existing email template that I have.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need a Visualforce Apex controller to retrieve any custom fields from the owner record.

Comment: @DavidCheng Thanks for the suggestion, David!  I ended up creating a custom formula field on the Enquiry object that returns the owner's Acuity Calendar ID.  So I access it with `relatedTo.Owner_Acuity_Calendar_ID__c`

Comment: The issue is due to Owner being a polymorphic field for custom objects (queue or user).